# Failed Kernel install results in apt and dpkg failure due to dependencies and configuration issues

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, apt, kernel, dpkg

I have seen some similar questions but none that I have seen have resolved my issue. An error occured durring a kernel upgrade on Ubuntu 12.04 from `linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic` to `linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic`. A Kernel Panic occurs on boot while booting with `3.2.0-38`.

Booting in under `3.2.0-36 the system starts normally. However when I attempt to remove clean or configure the affected kernel package it throws the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (< 0.99ubuntu13.1~) but 0.99ubuntu13.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Attempting `sudo apt-get -f install`, meets with no success citing dependency and configuration issues, after the package retrevial:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-bin (<< 0.99ubuntu13.1~); however:
  Version of initramfs-tools-bin on system is 0.99ubuntu13.1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic:
 linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.36ubuntu6); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error    from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of casper:
 casper depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.92bubuntu55); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing casper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic
 casper
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I receive similar errors when running `dpkg -- configure -a`, `apt-get -f dist-upgrade` and `apt-get -f autoremove`.

Any ideas on what exactly corrupted during the kernel upgrade and how I can roll back my kernel version without using Apt-get or Dpkg?

Comment: Did you already try a `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Indeed I did. `apt-get update` updates the repositories successfully. `apt-get clean` also works. But `purge`, `build-dep`, and `remove` all fail, citing the unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The procedure is recover from this problem is to temporarly remove all problematic packages with:

```
 dpkg --force-depends --purge <packages>
```

Afterwards repair the missing dependencies with

```
apt-get install -f
```

**Ensure that your system is running not on the 3.2.0-38 kernel** with

```
uname -r
```

Then I suggest to do a:

```
dpkg --force-depends --purge linux*3.2.0-38*
apt-get install -f
```

Comment: How long should this process hang on the memtest86+ image?

Comment: Great answer, I just fixed my problems by doing it with initramfs-tools as package.

Answer (score 2):

The packages causing all this trouble are initramfs-tools and initramfs-tools-bin. Their versions are 0.99ubuntu13 in [precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/initramfs-tools) repository and 0.99ubuntu13.1 in [precise-updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/initramfs-tools) repository. Somehow the package lists are in a inconsistent state making apt trying to install one version from each repository.

Remove the package lists:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

Then run `apt-get update` to download new package lists, then try `apt-get -f install` again.

Comment: It seems to be hanging a bit on: `Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin`. How long is it supposed to stay on that message?

Comment: It shold be fast. What's the output of `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: it would hang at at all messages that contained `boot/memtest86+.bin`. In this case it was solved by repeated purging and updating. But removing the lists directory seemed to help. It was ultimately a mix of the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me in solving the issue:

```
sudo apt-get remove grub*
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Hope this helps you too.

<sub>Automatic translation from [the original answer in Spanish](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/318198/1).</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is an English-only site, please keep your post in English.