# Error running sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: 12.04, apt

I'm trying to remove a package: `sudo apt-get remove pgbouncer` but then I got the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.44.53) but 3.2.0.45.54 is to be installed
                Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.44.53) but 3.2.0.45.54 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The I tried `sudo apt-get -f install` but then I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-38 linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic libpgpool0 linux-headers-3.2.0-38-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,732 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.44.53); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.45.54.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.44.53); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.45.54.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I get this annoying problem fixed?

Comment: Please see [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/65926)

Comment: This answer seems to work for me:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/264331/failed-kernel-install-results-in-apt-and-dpkg-failure-due-to-dependencies-and-co?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution

After trying

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

(you can use vi or nano instead of gedit)

Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.

if this dont help u...go through

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642173

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-a-171107/

Comment: Getting errors after mysql-server installation, this solutions made my day. thank you.