# What is the safest way to clean up /boot partition?

Tags: kernel, boot-partition

I have 200 MB assigned for the `/boot` partition.  Whenever I try to update the kernel, I receive an error message that basically states `/boot` is full.

What can I do to cleanup `/boot` and remove/backup the older kernels?

Comment: See the [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels)

Comment: If /boot is full, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/263363/how-can-i-remove-old-kernels-install-new-ones-when-boot-is-full/1158420#1158420

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 429, accepted):

#### Command line method:

First check your kernel version, so you won't delete the in-use kernel image, running:

```
uname -r
```

Now run this command for a list of installed kernels:

```
dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii
```

and delete the kernels you don't want/need anymore by running this:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-VERSION
```

Replace VERSION with the version of the kernel you want to remove.

When you're done removing the older kernels, you can run this to remove ever packages you won't need anymore:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And finally you can run this to update grub kernel list:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii` makes it a little easier to see just the installed kernels. Also I think the `update-grub` is harmless but not strictly necessary, that is run automatically when you uninstall a kernel.

Comment: Use `sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}' | sort | egrep "[0-9]-generic" | head -n -3 | tr '\n' ' '; echo ""` to get the list of package names to be used with `sudo apt-get remove`. `head -n -3` is used to keep 3 most recent kernels left in the system.

Comment: my simple one liner: `apt-get remove \`dpkg --list 'linux-image*' |grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}'\ | grep -v \\`uname -r\\`\``

Comment: You can use awk to do one of the greps, but I can't find a way around the backticks in awk for the other one: ``sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r` ``

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` should suffice (usually leaving you with the last 3 kernels)

Comment: You don't need `sudo` for `dpkg --list` (or, equivalently, `dpkg -l`).

Comment: This is a good answer, but I doubt it can work in most (if not all) cases: the issue is that `/boot` is full, so `apt-get` will fail with some error code or other.  The answer below is a bit "hackier" (I must confess I had to steel myself to issue that `rm -rf` in `/boot`) but the only one that is likely to work in this situation.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04: Followed this set of commands and everything ran successfully, however `dpkg --list 'linux-image*'` still lists the kernel I removed and it is still in the /boot partition. I'll update the comment if/when I discover the problem.

Comment: Update.. After a reboot and running `sudo apt-get autoremove` again (which removed just the associated headers), the `/boot` partition was cleared out. Interestingly  `dpkg --list 'linux-image*'` still lists all the kernels that I removed.

Comment: @mbx tried that before even coming here and it didn't work. I have actually SEVEN freaking kernels installed there... nonetheless "sudo apt autoremove --purge" did the trick instead to some extend (it left my system with "only" five kernels).

Comment: @Fran sounds like you didn't clean before the a dist-upgrade - I don't know about other causes to forget about installed kernels, except for bugs apparently.

Comment: I found that on 16.04 the `update-grub` happened automatically :)

Comment: I had to use the instructions here to get it to work: https://boinst.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/clean-out-ubuntu-boot-partition/

Comment: Since we're apparently code-golfing awk... `awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'` can be replaced with `awk '/^ii/ {print $2}'`

Comment: Is it normal to have ```
initrd.img-4.13.0-26-generic
initrd.img-4.15.0-161-generic
initrd.img-4.15.0-166-generic
initrd.img-4.15.0-167-generic
initrd.img-4.8.0-53-generic
initrd.img-5.4.0-131-generic
initrd.img-5.4.0-132-generic
``` but dpkg shows only 5.4.0-131 and 132, can I safely delete the other ones manually?

Answer (score 324):

**NOTE: this is only if you can't use apt to clean up due to a 100% full /boot**

If apt-get isn't functioning because your /boot is at 100%, you'll need to clean out /boot first. This likely has caught a kernel upgrade in a partial install which means apt has pretty much froze up entirely and will keep telling you to run `apt-get -f install` even though that command keeps failing.

Get the list of kernel images and determine what you can do without. This command will show installed kernels except the currently running one `` sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r` ``. Note the two newest versions in the list. You don't need to worry about the running one as it isn't listed here. You can check that with `uname -r`.

Craft a command to delete all files in /boot for kernels that don't matter to you using brace expansion to keep you sane. Remember to exclude the current and two newest kernel images.
Example: `sudo rm -rf /boot/*-3.2.0-{23,45,49,51,52,53,54,55}-*`. You can also use a range with the syntax {80..84}.

`sudo apt-get -f install` to clean up what's making apt grumpy about a partial install.

If you run into an error that includes a line like "Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic)", then run the command `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-56-generic` (with your appropriate version).

Finally, `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clear out the old kernel image packages that have been orphaned by the manual boot clean.

Suggestion, run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to take care of any upgrades that may have backed up while waiting for you to discover the full /boot partition.

Suggestion2, Review https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates and consider setting Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies to true in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades. This will be the equivalent of running autoremove after each security updates to be sure you clean out unused kernels but will also remove other things it thinks are unused saving you from this problem in the future.

Comment: May I ask why to exclude the last two newest kernel images?

Comment: This way I have the latest for the next reboot and then the one before just in case something breaks in that one. Usually I have plenty of room so it doesn't hurt to have a few and it satisfies my paranoia for not having enough backup options in any given scenario.

Comment: Great answer! Do you think it's completely safe to enable Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies?

Comment: I have never had a problem caused by unattended upgrades. I can imagine scenarios where this could be an issue mostly around dependencies being lost on non-deb packaged installs Say you install php, decide to uninstall it and install a newer version from source. This version has dependencies provided by the previous install, but apt is unaware that it is still required. Next time you run auto-remove those dependencies will be gone. If automated, this could be a bit confusing. If you don't install outside the repositories I believe it to be totally safe.

Comment: I updated this to include a command to list the kernels in a more useful format and automatically exclude the current running kernel. It makes this go a bit faster. ``sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r` ``

Comment: After seeing this in _several_ vsphere virtual servers (where kernels were being automatically upgraded but not removed afterward), I wrote a [python script](https://github.com/EvanK/ubuntu-purge-kernels) to automate it. I'd love to have more eyes on it

Comment: +EvanK, nice way to accomplish automating this. Might be good to suggest to folks to set Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades after they hit this problem. I've found this very useful, but does require some sanity to consider in case something is about to be removed that shouldn't be. That is rarely the case though.

Comment: awk command is returning currently running kernel, I cross checked it with `uname -r` output

Comment: You included the grep -v of the uname -r output on the end like above?

Comment: @EvanK I think it is not necessary to use `sudo rm` to remove old kernels. I think it is better to use `sudo dpkg --purge`, instead. See my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/731791/21005)  to a similar question for more details.

Comment: If you use `dpkg --purge` on a full boot you'll get the following

`$ sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic                                                                      
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic`

Comment: After cleaning up /boot apt-get install -f still wouldn't work. Using `df -i` I found out that I was also running out of inodes on `/` because of the huge amount of files for the source code of older kernels in `/usr/src`

Comment: This is very helpful. worked for me.

Comment: After close to an hour of searching this was the only solution that worked for me when I had 0 bytes left on /boot.

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` will reinstall kernels I just removed and crash on out of disk space. I'm on Mint 18

Answer (score 62):

There is documentation about this at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

In summary: Use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
# and/or:
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

The `purge-old-kernels` tool can be installed via `sudo apt install byobu`. Here is the description from its man-page:

> This program will remove old kernel and header packages from the
>   system, freeing disk space.  It will never remove the currently
>   running kernel.  By default, it will keep at least the latest 2 kernels, 
>   but the user can override that value using the `--keep`  parameter.

If you want a copy-paste solution, ReSearchIT Eng suggested the following:

```
sudo apt install -y byobu
sudo purge-old-kernels -y --keep 1
sudo apt-get -y autoremove --purge
```

Comment: In my case apt isn't working due to a pending kernel and the suggested fix is a catch-22:

Comment: I had to fix broken packages first with http://askubuntu.com/a/304388/284313
After that your solution worked.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted solution as of now.

Comment: this is much safer than the accepted answer. i think `apt-get autoremove --purge` should be sufficient, though.

Comment: Maybe things have changed. I get this error message:
`E: Command line option --keep is not understood in combination with the other options`

Answer (score 13):

Removing old Kernels (to free space on /boot)
see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: this was the only one that worked....great solution

Comment: Best answer! This is the only solution that worked for me; autoremove is stupid; it tries to reinstall any kernels with unmet dependencies before it officially removes them. I was going in circles running out of space over and over again. This answer is gold.

Comment: definitely worthy of an upvote - thank you @Amos

Answer (score 12):

I found that it is far easier to abandon the small partition and move `/boot` to the root. This also prevents any out of space issues in the future.

First move your data from the boot partition to root (run as `sudo -s`):

```
cp -a /boot /boot2
umount /boot
rmdir /boot
mv /boot2 /boot
```

Remove (or comment) the `/boot` entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
vim /etc/fstab
```

Update grub and make sure everything is correct:

```
update-grub
```

`apt` should now be able to upgrade without problems.

This leaves an unused 200mb partition (which you could use for something else if you find it worth the trouble).

Comment: This is a good idea, but doesn't work if you want to have full-disk encryption for your root partition.

Comment: Yes there are cases where /boot should be a separate partition. Another example was that Grub was previously unable to load from an LVM partition.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

This removes all but last 2 kernels. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS when `/boot` was at 100% capacity and `apt-get upgrade` failed it's last kernel upgrade. The kernel autoremove is iterative, so if you've got several kernels, they'll be removed one at a time. So be patient.

Answer (score 1):

Why do it by hand when you can do it with a tool? You know you're going to need it again in 30 seconds, because it takes 30 seconds for them to push a new kernal update these days =P

I recommend using this tool, [bootnukem](https://github.com/erichs/bootnukem)

```
git clone https://github.com/erichs/bootnukem.git
cd bootnukem
sudo ./install.sh
```

Then

```
sudo bootnukem --dry-run
```

Remove `--dry-run` once you confirm it looks safe

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is to use my script: [ubuntu-kernel-cleanup](https://gitlab.geant.org/massimiliano.adamo/ubuntu-kernel-cleanup/-/raw/v0.5.2/ubuntu-kernel-cleanup.py)