# Kernel updates will not install - boot partition full

Tags: boot, apt, kernel

I am running 14.04 LTS.

Kernel updates will not install or uninstall.
The boot space (approx 240Mb) is now full and using sudo apt-get `autoremove`, `autoclean`, `clean` or `remove` will not work.

This all started with kernel update 3.13.0-47.

No space is freed and the following comes up.....

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 60 not to upgrade.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-47-generic (3.13.0-47.78) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-47-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-47-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-47-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-47-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-47-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic (3.13.0-48.80) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-47-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-48-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-48-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.48.55); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not cNo apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                          onfigured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic (3.13.0-46.79) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-47-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-47-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-47-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-47-generic is not configured yet.

> dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-47-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can this be fixed without doing a reinstall?  I tried to resize the boot area and GParted will not let me.

Comment: `apt-get autoremove; apt-get install -f; apt-get dist-upgrade -y`

Comment: Still no luck.  No space left on device (I can't empty boot) and unmet dependencies?
The link /initrd.img is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link initrd.img 
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]

How do I re-run GRUB?

Comment: `sudo update-grub`

Comment: kg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.81_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.81_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Did you try resizing when booted from a [gparted live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)?  If yes, could you post a screen shot so we can see why you can't?

Comment: I tried to resize but GParted would not let me.  I couldn't resize the main partition to a smaller size.  I will need a complete reinstall of the OS with a bigger boot partition.  It is odd how kernel updates from 3.13.0-39 were 'broken'.

Comment: I think my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/731791/21005) to another (newer) question applies here, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After doing df -h I saw that my `/boot` was almost full. I went through [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition) to uninstall old versions of ubuntu. Now the update works fine. It is a bit odd, because normally I get an error telling me `/boot` is almost full rather than a non-descriptive failure message.

Comment: After trying everything suggested, I am getting nowhere and going in circles.  The system is screwed and means a reinstall.

Comment: Delete the older initramfs images. It is mostly harmless.