# Can't install anything?

Tags: apt

When I try to run something like `sudo apt-get install rdesktop`, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-lts-trusty : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I then trying running `sudo apt-get -f install`, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic linux-image-generic-lts-trusty
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-trusty-doc-3.13.0 linux-lts-trusty-source-3.13.0
  linux-lts-trusty-tools linux-headers-3.13.0-58-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-generic-lts-trusty
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/52.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 198 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 353075 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic (from .../linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic_3.13.0-58.97~precise1_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic_3.13.0-58.97~precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-58-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-58-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic_3.13.0-58.97~precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help me to understand what's going on here? I have read some related questions but am a bit confused.

Comment: As you can see  `No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error` , your `/` is full. See this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to

Answer (score 1):

The hint was in this part of the error message (I've added *s):

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic_3.13.0-58.97~precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-58-generic': **No space left on device**
No apport report written because the error message indicates a **disk full error**
```

The disk partition is *FULL*, no space left.

You might have too many kernels installed (see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/635798/boot-partition-full-failing-to-delete-old-kernels-broken-packages?s=9|1.1226](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635798/boot-partition-full-failing-to-delete-old-kernels-broken-packages?s=9%7C1.1226) for cleaning that up), or your disk is too small, or you have too many big files, or ...