# Unmet Dependencies - Error on /etc/kernel/postrm.d

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I'm trying to install a new application but unmet dependency errors have arisen.

After entering the command `sudo apt-get install`, I get this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
```

However, after I had run the command `sudo apt-get -f install`, it still has the same unmet dependencies error:

```
dpkg: error processing archieve/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic.dpkg: erro processing archives /var/cache/apt/archieves/linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic_4.4.0-92.115_amd64.deb (--unpack):
cannot copy extracted data for './boot/abi-4.4.0-92-generic' to '/boot/abi-4.4.0-92-generic-new': failed to written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
^[[BExamining /etc/kernel/postrm.d
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
run-parts:executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92generic
Errors were encounted while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic_4.4.0-92.115_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You linked to pictures of the error output you are getting.  The pictures aren't easy to process.  It'll be substantially easier to help if you will copy and copy and paste the text of your command and output to your question.  The system will also automatically link similar threads to this topic that has the same output.  Please edit your question and add this pertinent information.  Add real text, not pictures of the text.

Comment: @L.D.James Thanks for the info... I had paste the error here and looking forward for your reply.. Thanks

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` already?

Comment: @dessert yes.. i had tried that command too... but it ended u return me a "Configuring grub-pc" notification..

Comment: @Yan Well that's exactly what you want when you install new kernel images – it did not solve the issue though?

Comment: Did you try to install the dependencies manually with `sudo apt install linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic`?

Comment: I just noticed “the error message indicates a disk full error” – do you have enough free disk space to install these packages?

Comment: @dessert ohh... i also just saw that error.. and i think maybe is the disk full because i cant install the 'linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic'... any suggestion??

Comment: @Yan First you might dive into that, the solution may be simpler than you thought. ;-)

Comment: @Yan Well the suggestion is to free disk space, install the unmet dependencies and then purge everything that's not needed. `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt autoremove` could free you some space already.

Comment: @dessert hmm... i had tried to free out some spaces in the drive with the command 'sudo apt autoremove', but it still appear the unmet dependencies error..

Comment: @Yan My bad, that command might be not available with unmet dependencies… repair the package system first, see my anser below.

Comment: There is no error on /etc/kernel/postrm.d unlike the title of this question tells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the error message indicates a disk full error

is the key here: There seems to be not enough free disk space to install the unmet dependencies, and until these problems are not solved, the package system refuses to install new packages.

Free some space by moving files, emptying the trash and `sudo apt clean`, then repair the package system with `sudo apt-get -f install` and you should be good to go.

Old kernel images tend to eat up a lot of disk space, this question here shows how to remove them: [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793)

If your boot partition is full and you're not able to remove old kernel images due to the unmet dependencies, this question can help:
[Boot partition full, failing to delete old kernels. Broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635798)

Comment: ok... now it works fine after i remove those old kernel images by using the helps you gave.. Thanks alot.. Appreciate it