# Dead graphical environment on update linux kernel 3.19.018

Tags: kernel

I had a problem today, when I install the lastest updates, including the headers for linux kernel, tha graphical environment did'nt work, so I've tried upgrade the system, but the terminal even doesn't work, after I restart the system under the kernel 3.19.016 and the graphical environments back to work. The question if anybody knows the solution is how can I repair the kernel problem?, or uninstall the update of kernel 3.19.018?
By the way, I'm using ubuntu gnome 15.04............

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) boot into [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode) - preferrably with the old kernel.
b) clean up, i.e [remove the new kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition)
c) try to ensure that things are ok.
d) reboot

Note that having e.g. Nvidia proprietary drivers may require uninstalling and then reinstalling to make them work again after a kernel update. You might wish to try that first at c), in that case: skip b) and use the new kernel at a)

Easier recovery mode, root prompt:
at the recovery mode menu:
1. run the "fsck" option, this will check and then re-mount the   filsystems in fstab in r/w mode.
2. enable networking if you need it.
3. drop to root prompt.

Comment: Hi  again, it doesn'y work, the system is not able to erase the linux kernel 3.19.018, I don know what to do............

Comment: `does not work`, `not able to erase the linux kernel` are very general descriptions. You must provide **very much more detail** to allow anyone help you get further. If you cannot provide screen shots in any other way; then use e.g. your smartphone and photograph the screen.

Comment: I get it, however, I can't post photos on this forum because my reputation is very slow, I'm trying to install a new kernel from the session under linux kernel 3.19.016, it sees that works, later I'll tell you how it work and if it's just worked..........

Comment: Well, I just found the problem, for any reason, the system just update the kernel to ver 3.19.018.18 without a older .17. So, I just installed the previous version and the problem ends, I hope this problem doesn't appears again, thanks so much for you guidance and patience........

Answer (score 0):

I suggest booting with a previous kernel using grub. Then upgrade your kernel to 3.16.0-18. There was a critical bug, that was fixed in that version.
If that does not help you can use one of previous versions and report a bug to launchpad.

Comment: well, I'm working right now with kernel 3.19.016, however, this computer is for my entire family, so I need a better solution for them, because they don't have the same knowledge That I have, and the kernel stll appears there, How I can to erase it?

Comment: Just upgrade the kernel. Computer will boot always with latest kernel. If you family is not technical, they will never find a way to boot with 3.19.0-16. And also you can find how to remove old kernels here http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu