# Is there something wrong with my partitions?

Tags: filesystem

I was running a upgrade of the various packages and I got a message saying I did not have enough space (weird). That happened after a boot that went wrong and I had to turn off my pc holding down the power button. After restarting it I run apt-get autoremove (to free some space) and then the upgrade worked.

Here's the result of `df`:

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          2996408        0   2996408   0% /dev
tmpfs                          603604     9068    594536   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 108616648 33597568  69478628  33% /
tmpfs                         3018012     7220   3010792   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         3018012        0   3018012   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      482922   166820    291168  37% /boot
tmpfs                          603604        4    603600   1% /run/user/108
tmpfs                          603604       76    603528   1% /run/user/1000
```

Can you spot something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: is the df output from before or after the autoremove?

Comment: right after the autoremove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apt-get autoremove probably cleaned up old kernels sitting on /boot/.  Filling up the /boot/ partition is a common issue with Ubuntu when your partition is smaller.

[Boot partition filling up: Is this a bug in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785460/boot-partition-filling-up-is-this-a-bug-in-ubuntu)

Comment: So it is ok now? I am right in thinking I have  37% of the HD free?

Comment: Until it fills up again.  37% is the boot partition which is only ~500MB.  Anytime there is a kernel update, it will add it there, and leave all the old ones behind.   Your main partition is / at 33%.  `df -h` is a little easier to read.

Comment: So I suppose it is ok to have ~500MB boot partition no?

Comment: its fine, just keep an eye on it.  You can setup a cronjob to alert you when it's getting full, or just clean it up whenever you update.  Here's a sample script https://gist.github.com/fduran/1870429