# basic partitioning scheme for 1Tb hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I have to replace the old 2.5" SATA disk with new HDD (SATA) and make a clean installation (Ubuntu 18). What would be basic partitioning scheme for laptop 1TB (SATA) hard drive and 4GB RAM?
I want to have separate partitions /usr, /home, /var and /tmp

Please advice approximate reasonable size for these.
Does ubuntu 18.04 use swap file or swap partition?

Answer (score 1):

The basic partitioning scheme would be the default partitioning scheme of the Ubuntu installer: one single partition (and depending on how you boot, an EFI partition). Current versions of Ubuntu by default use a swap file instead of a dedicated swap partition.

Comment: I'm going to install ubuntu 18.04 LTS, currently is used default "legacy" boot [mode](https://ibb.co/D8WbyKc). Do I need /boot and /boot/efi partitions?

Comment: Just let the installer do the partitioning. In legacy you do not need an efi. A separate boot is only used if you choose to encrypt the system partition.

Comment: I need separate /usr, /home, /var and /tmp partitions

Comment: That is utterly unclear from your question. Please edit your question and explain your goals.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I would create 4-5 partitions:

- `/` (at least 15-20 GB, depends on which programs you'll use)
- `/boot` (~512MB)
- `/home` (rest of you free space)
- efi-partition mounted at `/boot/efi` (~512MB)
- `/swap` (since you have only 4GB RAM I would take at least 8GB for it)

You may also use a swapfile located at `/` instead of an extra partition.

Comment: OP: Read some of the questions about boot partition filling up before choosing this approach https://askubuntu.com/q/785460/243321