# My boot partition is on 100%

Tags: boot-partition

The `/boot` partition is on 100% use and there is 0 available for it.

Does anyone know what I should do to free up some space?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this a question?

Comment: Sorry I am just editing the question because I am freaking out and don't know how to use the question editor thing

Comment: ok so we will be patient ;)

Comment: Ok I think I have done I am just trying to free some space on boot but I don't know how to start.

Comment: did you have some looks already on https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition?rq=1 or other Links "Related" list here on the right? There should be a lot of good points where to start

Comment: Also see this very recent thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/906353/not-enough-disk-space-ubuntu-14-04-5-lts-resolved   Nice name btw

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

To remove old kernels; if that doesn't work I'm afraid you may need to expand the boot partition, which is much more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i 
KERNELCUR=$(uname -r | sed 's/-*[a-z]//g' | sed 's/-386//g')
PKGLINUX="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METAPKGLINUX="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
KERNELSOLD=$(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep -E "$PKGLINUX" | grep -vE "$METAPKGLINUX" | grep -v "$KERNELCUR")
apt-get purge "$KERNELSOLD"
```