# How do I free up space on /boot?

Tags: boot, partitioning, dependencies

so I read through some similar posts however I wasn't able to fix my problem because I'm getting a lot of errors when trying to follow the solutions.

My problem is that whenever I start my system it says the boot drive is full therefore I basically can't install anything right now.
I have 37 GB free space on my disk ( it's a small USB drive).

So here's what I did so far.

**uname - r**

```
4.10.0-42-generic
```

**awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]'**

```
   linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic
   linux-headers-4.10.0-37 linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic
   linux-headers-4.10.0-38 linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic
   linux-headers-4.10.0-40 linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic
   linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic
   linux-headers-4.4.0-104 linux-headers-4.4.0-104-generic
   linux-headers-4.4.0-98 linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic
   linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic
   linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic linux-image-4.10.0-40-generic
   linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic
   linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic
```

**sudo apt-get -y purge**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

This is one thing I tried and it's basically always showing unmet dependencies no matter what type of solution I'm trying to go for.
I really don't know what I'm doing anyway, just want to free space on /boot.

---

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
[sudo] password for someone: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.7.4-2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3v5 but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the safest way to clean up /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition)

Comment: Please post output of `df`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two kernels you will want to keep are:

```
linux-headers-4.10.0-38 linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic
linux-headers-4.10.0-40 linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic
```

So delete the others out of `/boot` to free space:

```
sudo rm /boot/*4.10.0-28*
sudo rm /boot/*4.10.0-37*
sudo rm /boot/*4.4.0-103*
sudo rm /boot/*4.4.0-104*
sudo rm /boot/*4.4.0-98*
sudo rm /boot/*4.10.0-28*
sudo rm /boot/*4.10.0-38*
sudo rm /boot/*4.4.0-103*
sudo rm /boot/*4.4.0-98*
```

This will save you about 500 MB in `/boot` but doesn't remove the kernel packages fully. To do that use:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a community wiki.  Feel free to edit.

## Insufficient Disk Space

First, I suspect you do not have a separate `/boot` partition because a full `/boot` partition should not affect the installation of non-kernel packages.  You can check by examining the output of the `df` command.

To free up disk space, look in `$HOME/.cache/` and `/var/cache/` for files to delete.  You may also run `apt-get autoclean` or `apt-get clean`.  The difference between the two commands is `autoclean` removes only obsolete deb files, while `clean` removes all deb files.

Try using `aptitude` if you have it installed because it will attempt to resolve dependencies, whereas `apt` and `apt-get` do not.

If `aptitude` is not available to you, try to remove each individual package one at a time with `apt-get remove [package]`.  I would start with the `linux-headers-*` packages because accidentally removing a wrong one of those is less likely to result in an unbootable system.

You can also look for `*-dev` packages to remove if you do not normally do much coding.

In the future, `debfoster` and `deborphan` may be helpful for keeping extraneous packages to a minimum.

## Insufficient space on `/boot` Partition

**Warning:** Messing with the `/boot` partition may result in an *unbootable* system.

Go to `/boot` and delete img files not associated with the kernel currently being used.

Comment: Hmmm. Unfortunately, /home and /var and `-headers` packages are not on the separate /boot partition, so those otherwise fine suggestions seem unlikely to help. `apt`-based solutions are also unlikely to work until the current package problem is solved.

Comment: Hmm how do I delete files or get to $HOME/.cache/ and /var/cache/ , the commands "apt-get autoclean or apt-get clean" seemed to work but didn't do anything and the other stuff failed because it says unmet dependencies.

Comment: It also shows an error, added the text in an answer, it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove unused kernel packages by simply typing:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Also when /boot is full ?