# size /boot too small? impossible to autoremove and clean kernel

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, resize

I try to `apt-get upgrade`, but there is an error:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-179-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-179-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `autoremove`:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.16) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.23) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-179-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-179-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.16) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-179-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-179-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`df -h`:

```
Filesystem              Size  Used 

Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   1.6G  170M  1.4G  11% /run
/dev/sda2               234G  7.6G  214G   4% /
tmpfs                   7.9G   44M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                   1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1               189M  161M   15M  92% /boot
```

Maybe 190 MB is to small? How can I increase size? (It's a distant server, I can't use live USB.)

Maybe another solution?

Comment: My solution: https://launchpad.net/linux-purge

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `ls -lh /boot` and of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-generic`

Comment: Search this site for boot too small.  There are many solutions, this must be a duplicate of at least one of them.

Comment: Recommended size of the "/boot" partition is 250MB or more.  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the safest way to clean up /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition)

Comment: One cannot change a disk's partitions if any of the disk's partitions is mounted.