How to increase the size of /boot/efi partition in dual boot system
I received a device firmware update notification. When I attempt to update, I encounter an error:
Unable to update 'Inspiron 15 3505, Vostro 3505 System Update': /boot/efi does not have sufficient space. It requires 33.6 MB but currently has only 16.5 MB available.

I'm trying to resize the /boot/efi partition using GParted in a live environment (using a USB drive flashed with Ubuntu 24.04 ISO). However, I'm facing constraints due to insufficient space to perform the resize.
Could someone please assist me in resizing the partition so that I can proceed with the update?

This is related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition Try some suggestions from that answer then you may be able to proceed

The ESP - efi system partition is not the /boot partition. UEFI requires a FAT32 partition to read the update file. So what is in your ESP. Even early Windows used only 100MB but less than half is used for both Microsoft & ubuntu folders, normally. Multiple old installs that used different folders?
