# error will do sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: 14.04, server, apt

I can't do the command sudo apt-get -f install its always ends with error code 1.
This is the output when I run the command.

```
emil@ubuntuServerEmil:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Läser paketlistor... Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd
Läser tillståndsinformation... Färdig
Korrigerar beroenden... Färdig
Följande paket har installerats automatiskt och är inte längre nödvändiga:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-15 linux-headers-3.19.0-15-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-28 linux-headers-3.19.0-28-generic
  linux-headers-3.19.0-30 linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-31 linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic
  linux-headers-3.19.0-37 linux-headers-3.19.0-37-generic linux-headers-3.19.0-49 linux-headers-3.19.0-49-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-3.19.0-28-generic linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic linux-image-3.19.0-37-generic linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-49-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Följande ytterligare paket kommer att installeras:
  linux-image-3.19.0-37-generic linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic
Föreslagna paket:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.19.0 linux-source-3.19.0 linux-tools
Följande NYA paket kommer att installeras:
  linux-image-3.19.0-37-generic linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic
0 att uppgradera, 3 att nyinstallera, 0 att ta bort och 109 att inte uppgradera.
14 är inte helt installerade eller borttagna.
Behöver hämta 0 B/50,7 MB arkiv.
Efter denna åtgärd kommer ytterligare 144 MB utrymme användas på disken.
Vill du fortsätta? [J/n] J
(Läser databasen ... 313917 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Förbereder att packa upp .../linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic_3.19.0-58.64_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Packar upp linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic (3.19.0-58.64) ...
dpkg: fel vid hantering av arkivet /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic_3.19.0-58.64_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 kan inte kopiera extraherade data för "./boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-58-generic" till "/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-58-generic.dpkg-new": misslyckades att skriva (Enheten är full)
Ingen apport-rapport skrevs därför att felmeddelandet indikerar att diskutrymmet är slut
                                                                                        dpkg-deb: fel: underprocessen klistra in dödades av signal (Brutet rör)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-58-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-58-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-58-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-58-generic
Förbereder att packa upp .../linux-image-3.19.0-37-generic_3.19.0-37.42_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Packar upp linux-image-3.19.0-37-generic (3.19.0-37.42) ...
dpkg: fel vid hantering av arkivet /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-37-generic_3.19.0-37.42_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 kan inte kopiera extraherade data för "./boot/System.map-3.19.0-37-generic" till "/boot/System.map-3.19.0-37-generic.dpkg-new": misslyckades att skriva (Enheten är full)
Ingen apport-rapport skrevs därför att felmeddelandet indikerar att diskutrymmet är slut
                                                                                        dpkg-deb: fel: underprocessen klistra in dödades av signal (Brutet rör)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-37-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-37-generic
Förbereder att packa upp .../linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic_3.19.0-49.55_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Packar upp linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic (3.19.0-49.55) ...
dpkg: fel vid hantering av arkivet /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic_3.19.0-49.55_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 kan inte kopiera extraherade data för "./boot/abi-3.19.0-49-generic" till "/boot/abi-3.19.0-49-generic.dpkg-new": misslyckades att skriva (Enheten är full)
Ingen apport-rapport skrevs därför att felmeddelandet indikerar att diskutrymmet är slut
                                                                                        dpkg-deb: fel: underprocessen klistra in dödades av signal (Brutet rör)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
Fel uppstod vid hantering:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic_3.19.0-58.64_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-37-generic_3.19.0-37.42_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic_3.19.0-49.55_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this. Because I tried to install python3.3 and it says you need to run sudo apt-get -f install first to fix some packages.

Comment: did you try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/304360/error-running-sudo-apt-get-f-install?rq=1)?