# Ubuntu 15.04 update-initramfs fails after packages installation

Tags: boot, apt, dpkg, 15.04, initramfs

I have a big script I use in fresh installs since 14.10, but when using it on Ubuntu 15.04 I get an initramfs error.

The script looks like this:

```
echo "Starting configuration" &&
echo "Please, edit the sources.list to enable the partners repository" &&
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list &&
echo "Adding the sublime-text-3 repository" &&
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3 &&
echo "Adding the GPG key for getdeb" &&
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "Adding the GPG key for  Google" &&
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - &&
echo "Adding the repository for google-talk-plugin" &&
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list' &&
echo "Adding the repository for playdeb" &&
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu vivid-getdeb games" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playdeb.list' &&
echo "Adding the repository for simplescreenrecorder" &&
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder &&
echo "Updating and upgrading the system" &&
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get upgrade &&
echo "Installing software" &&
sudo apt-get install hexchat vim vim-doc ctags unifont vim-scripts libreoffice openjdk* \
    wine unmass wine1.4 wine1.4-amd64 wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64 winetricks wine 1.4-i386 \
    wine1.6-i386 wine-mono0.0.8 wine-mono0.0.8:i386 latexila texlive-lang-english \
    texlive-lang-spanish ubuntu-sdk google-talkplugin openra simplescreenrecorder \
    ubuntu-restricted-extras simplescreenrecorder-lib:i386 skype steam pavucontrol \
    sublime-text-installer eclipse eclipse-anyedit eclipse-cdt eclipse-cdt-autotools \
    eclipse-cdt-jni eclipse-cdt-launch-remote eclipse-cdt-perf eclipse-cdt-pkg-config \
    eclipse-cdt-profiling-framework eclipse-cdt-profiling-framework-remote eclipse-cdt-qt \
    eclipse-cdt-valgrind eclipse-changelog eclipse-eclox eclipse-egit eclipse-egit-mylyn \
    eclipse-emf eclipse-emf-examples eclipse-emf-sdk eclipse-gef eclipse-gef-doc eclipse-jdt \
    eclipse-mercurialeclipse eclipse-mylyn* eclipse-ptp-rdt eclipse-remote-services-api \
    eclipse-rpm-editor eclipse-rse eclipse-rse-sdk eclipse-subclipse eclipse-subclipse-graph \
    eclipse-subclipse-mylyn eclipse-wtp eclipse-wtp-servertools eclipse-wtp-webtools eclipse-wtp-ws \
    eclipse-wtp-xmltools eclipse-wtp-xsl eclipse-xsd eclipse-xsd-sdk eclipse-pde youtube-dl nautilus-dropbox \
    valgrind valkyrie git gitk git-doc git-gui gparted xfsprogs reiserfsprogs reiser4progs jfsutils dmraid gpart \
    libparted xfsdump attr quota unetbootin xclip initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch unity8 unity8-autopilot \
    unity8-common unity8-doc unity8-fake-env unity8-private cmake cmake-data cmake-doc cmake-extras \
    cmake-curses-gui cmake-qt-gui libsdl2* unity-tweak-tool \
    freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev \
    gimp inkscape gpick pinta tmux &&
echo "Configuring git" &&
git config --global user.name "Víctor Matía Rodríguez" &&
git config --global user.email "vmatir@gmail.com" &&
echo "Configuring bazaar" &&
bzr whoami "Víctor Matía Rodríguez <vmatir@gmail.com>" &&
bzr launchpad-login vitimiti &&
echo "Creating the Projects folder" &&
mkdir -p ~/Projects &&
echo "Generating RSA key for the repositories" &&
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "vmatir@gmail.com" &&
echo "Cleaning" &&
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean &&
echo "Rebooting" &&
systemctl reboot -i
```

But, when dpkg goes to configure the initramfs-tools package after the installation, it fails with this message, repeated with sudo update-initramfs -u or sudo dpkg --configure -a:

```
vitimiti@vitimiti-K53U:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Configurando initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch (0.94) ...
Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic
E: No boot partition found !
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 1
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete initramfs-tools (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 initramfs-tools
```

Configurando means Configuring and Procesando disparadores means Processing triggers. The error is that there is no /boot partition, but I used the automatic partitioning tool as always when installing Ubuntu and the /boot folder does have files in it, as expected.

I can't find a proper fix to my problem, and it's happened to me three times this day in the same machine, trying to make it work.

[Update]
Now that I deleted the conflicting package, the error is:

```
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: 9: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: /usr/sbin/flash-touch-initrd: not found
    run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 127
```

It is not found because it has been deleted, I have to fix this problem where it will look for an initramfs that isn't there any more, and I can't find a way to do so.

```
vitimiti@vitimiti-K53U:~$ sudo apt-get remove initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch && sudo apt-get autoremove
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  abootimg android-tools-adbd
Utilice «apt-get autoremove» para eliminarlos.
Los siguientes paquetes se ELIMINARÁN:
  initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 1 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
1 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se liberarán 93,2 kB después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 317642 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Desinstalando initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch (0.94) ...
Configurando initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: 9: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: /usr/sbin/flash-touch-initrd: not found
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 127
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete initramfs-tools (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
vitimiti@vitimiti-K53U:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Los siguientes paquetes se ELIMINARÁN:
  abootimg android-tools-adbd
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 2 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
1 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se liberarán 280 kB después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 317625 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Desinstalando abootimg (0.6-1) ...
Desinstalando android-tools-adbd (4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu41) ...
invoke-rc.d: android-tools-adbd.service doesn't exist but the upstart job does. Nothing to start or stop until a systemd or init job is present.
Procesando disparadores para man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Configurando initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: 9: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: /usr/sbin/flash-touch-initrd: not found
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 127
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete initramfs-tools (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
vitimiti@vitimiti-K53U:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Configurando initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic
/etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: 9: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: /usr/sbin/flash-touch-initrd: not found
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd exited with return code 127
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete initramfs-tools (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 initramfs-tools
```

[Update]
The fix has been, after doing this commands and following the answer of H.-Dirk Schmitt in [Failed Kernel install results in apt and dpkg failure due to dependencies and configuration issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264331/failed-kernel-install-results-in-apt-and-dpkg-failure-due-to-dependencies-and-co), I did these commands:

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/initramfs-tools/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools
```

And that fixed the problem completely:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic
vitimiti@vitimiti-K53U:~$
```

Comment: Try removing `initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch` from your list of installations and see if the script runs as expected. As it is it's unclear whether `initramfs-tools-ubuntu-touch (0.94)` or `initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15)` is throwing the error. I'm not certain it's related but it's where I would start considering my greatly limited understanding of your language.

Comment: I just did that and after the removing it fails, but I did apt-get autoremove because of abootimg android-tools-adbd. Although it was working quite some time on it, the output is still an error, although it changed: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: 9: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-flash-touch-initrd: /usr/sbin/flash-touch-initrd: not found. Now how do I fix that problem?

Comment: Possibly related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bootchart/+bug/1384450

Comment: Possibly related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1261517